# how do I convert LocalDate to String form so it prints out the date inputed

Tags: java, string, model-view-controller, crud, localdate

```
   public void displayDVD(DVD dvd) {
       if (dvd != null) {
           io.print(dvd.getTitle());
           io.print(dvd.getReleaseDate());
           io.print(dvd.getMpaaRating());
           io.print(dvd.getDirectorsName());
           io.print(dvd.getStudio());
           io.print(dvd.getUserRating());
```

I need to display the getReleaseDate, but it's telling me I can't because its a LocalDate and can't be a string. Probably a rookie look, but really can't find a way around it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with the [Date Time Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html), in particular [Parsing and Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public void displayDVD(DVD dvd) {
    if (dvd != null) {
        io.print(dvd.getTitle());
        io.print(dvd.getReleaseDate().toString());
        io.print(dvd.getMpaaRating());
        io.print(dvd.getDirectorsName());
        io.print(dvd.getStudio());
        io.print(dvd.getUserRating());
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thought about it, but didn't try to see if it works. I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [Date Time Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html), in particular [Parsing and Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)

Something like...

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
```

prints out...

```
2021-11-18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overloading io.print or convert dvd.getReleaseDate() to a string.
like this

```
private void print(LocalDate localDate) {
    System.out.println(localDate.toString());
    // use toString() or format
    System.out.println(format(localDate));
}

private String format(LocalDate localDate) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return formatter.format(localDate);
}

public void displayDVD(DVD dvd) {
    if (dvd != null) {
        io.print(dvd.getTitle());
        // format
        io.print(format(dvd.getReleaseDate()));
        io.print(dvd.getMpaaRating());
        io.print(dvd.getDirectorsName());
        io.print(dvd.getStudio());
        io.print(dvd.getUserRating());
    }
}
```